# Using the PHP spl_autoload_register() with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload, spl-autoload-register

Please how can I use spl_autoload_register() with Codeigniter? I need to do this because Im using Codeigniter with another framework which also uses autoload.

I saw something here

[PHP spl_autoload_register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710480/php-spl-autoload-register)

but **I dont know how to target the CodeIgniter autoload**. Im new to OOP and Codeigniter. Thanks a lot!

The above link has this:

```
function autoload_services($class_name){
    $file = 'services/' . $class_name. '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)){
        require_once($file);
    }
}

function autoload_vos($class_name){
    $file = 'vos/' . $class_name. '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)){
        require_once($file);
    }
}

function autoload_printers($class_name){
    $file = 'printers' . $class_name. '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)){
        require_once($file);
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_services');
spl_autoload_register('autoload_vos');
spl_autoload_register('autoload_printers');
```

Comment: What do you mean "target the CodeIgniter autoload"?  You want to build your own autoloader to load the CI classes?  Or you want to load your own classes along side of the CI autoloader (if it has one, I have no idea)?

Comment: Yes, ircmaxwell, I need to use the spl_autoload_register to autoload from either Codeigniter or the other framework (Flourish). i.e. if a class is called, if its not found in Flourish it checks CI and vice versa. Currently, I get exception errors "Class could not be loaded" on the pages. But when I disable the autoload for either one, it runs fine. Its the combination that I need. DO you get it now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/73804/#366081 and some bits of information from some CI folk that I follow on twitter (I asked em): [Eric Barnes](http://twitter.com/ericlbarnes), [Dan Horrigan](http://twitter.com/dhorrigan), [Phil Sturgeon](http://twitter.com/PhilSturgeon) and [Zack Kitzmiller](http://twitter.com/ZackKitzmiller), I found a solution. If you are a CodeIgniter n00b like me, you may like to follow these guys.

I deleted init.php and config.php, then jammed the following into the bottom of my CI's config.php (I am also autoloading from a custom library called mylibrary).

```
function multi_auto_require($class) {
if(stripos($class, 'CI') === FALSE && stripos($class, 'PEAR') === FALSE) {
    foreach (array('flourish', 'mylibrary') as $folder){
        if (is_file(APPPATH."../auxengines/{$folder}/{$class}.php")){
            include_once APPPATH."../auxengines/{$folder}/{$class}.php";
        }
    }
}
}
```

> spl_autoload_register('multi_auto_require');

Works brilliantly. Thanks, people!

Comment: I had to add 'MY' and 'MX' to that, as I'm using the HMVC extension, just in case anyone finds this answer doesn't quite solve the problem.

Comment: You deleted config.php and then jammed into the bottom of my CI's config.php? :|

Comment: This was 9 years ago, way before PHP started having better structure - I was new, and I can hardly remember the project now. I think I was combining two PHP frameworks, and there were some conflicts in the autoload function from both frameworks, so doing this helped "join" both configs.

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh, I see now (after looking at [a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823192/conflict-between-codeigniter-autoload-and-flourish-autoload-functions) you asked)...  You're having a problem because there are 2 defined `__autoload` functions (and hence result in a parse error)...

To fix it, simply rename one of them to something else, and then right after definition call `spl_autoload_register('yournewfunctionname');`...

That should be all there is to it, so long as I understand your problem...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ircmaxwell. I renamed the flourish autoload function to ___autoload_flourish and after definition I called spl_autoload_register('___autoload_flourish'); but no, its not working still. I get the very same errors. I think I will need to understand how CI does its own autoloading cos it is not the usual PHP autoload function :( What do you think please?

Comment: Does either throw an exception or issue an error if it can't load the class?  Can you post the code of both functions?