# codeigniter rest server issue

Tags: codeigniter-2

i'm working with codeigniter rest server by phil sturgeon. I'm following net.tutsplus tutorial for restfull services [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) . I've installed the rest server locally and working intially to see how it works before installing it on server.

I'm having alot of problems from the starts.
i included the REST_Controller.php file in my main controller and after that line when i do this :

```
 class Courses extends REST_Controller {

  function index (){
  $this->load->view('index');
  }

}
```

it gives error saying:
Fatal error: Class 'REST_Controller' not found.
But if i replace REST_Controller with CI_Controller it loads the index view.
I'm stuck on this for 4 hours and nothing is working my way.
need your advice guyz
thnx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver#installation

Quick way would be to add before `class Courses extends REST_Controller {`

```
require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');
```

Also, consider using `__autoload` [Using the PHP spl_autoload_register() with Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842257/using-the-php-spl-autoload-register-with-codeigniter)

HTH

Comment: Also the function name becomes index_get(). If your method is post then function should end with _post.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```
class Courses extends REST_Controller {

 function index_get (){
   $this->response(array('success' => 'Yes it is working'), 200);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function on the top of your config.php file. In this way you don't need to include any file to any controller who extends REST_Controller.

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```